# RxJava 1.3 - amb does not subscribe nor unsubscribe from slower stream

Tags: rx-java

```
    Observable<Object> obs1 = Observable
            .create(subscriber -> subscriber.onNext("obs 1 event"))
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("obs1 sub"))
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> System.out.println("obs1 unsub"));

    Observable<Object> obs2 = Observable
            .create(subscriber -> subscriber.onNext("obs 2 event"))
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("obs2 sub"))
            .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> System.out.println("obs2 unsub"));

    Observable
            .amb(obs1, obs2)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

    Thread.sleep(500);
```

obs2 doOn* methods are supposed to be called and only 1 event out of two should be emited. Program output:

```
obs1 sub
obs 1 event
```

No *subscribe methods of obs2 are invoked.

Comment: You have synchronous sources and as such, amb doesn't try to subscribe to the second one since the first one already won the race at that point.

Comment: @akarnokd - I am afraid I don't understand. 
How are they synchronous?
When I replace create with just it works as I would expekt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJava sources and operators are synchronous by default unless they use a scheduler to introduce asynchrony. None of your code above has any scheduler involved so the execution will be synchronous. `amb` doesn't try to subscribe to the second one since the first one already won the race at that point.

> When I replace create with `just` it works as I would expekt

The reason `just` produces different result is backpressure which you didn't implement with your deprecated `create` usage. `amb` subscribes to the sources first and then requests from the sources, thus you get the subscription side-effects. With your broken implementation, the first source pushes its items through right away and thus brings `amb` to its win-state, preventing the second subscription from happening.